# RegEx:Replace: Dequote integers

Tags: regex

So, I have a file with a large JSON array of objects, and unfortunately, every field is wrapped in double quotes. Two fields in particular (Latitude and Longitude) needs to have the quotes removed.

I just want to use RegEx within an editors find/replace feature to remove the quotes...but I am struggling to come up with the RegEx.

This is very specific, I am just hoping there is a RegEx guru out there that could point me in the right direction on how to free the 37 and the -122 below from their quoted prisons.

```
    {
    "ClubId": "TestWith01",
    "ClubName": "TestWith01",
    "_DistrictNumber": "K05",
    "MeetingDay1": "2nd & 4th MO",
    "MeetingTime1": "6:30 PM",
    "MeetingDay2": "",
    "URL": "http://www.someurl.com",
    "Latitude": "37",
    "Longitude": "-122",
    "MeetingAddress": {
        "Address1": "Sample With Quotes",
        "Address2": "",
        "Address3": "",
        "City": "Treasure Island",
        "State": "FL",
        "PostalCode": "33706",
        "Country": "United States"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = subject.replace(/"(-?\d+)"/g, "$1");
```

This should replace anything that has an optional minus, followed by 1+ digits. You did not specify your language, so I guessed javascript.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it got me 90% of the way there...I am using an editor (TextMate2, to be specific), and what worked is: in the find textbox: "Latitude": "(-?\d+.\d+)"    in the replace textbox "Latitude": $1     and I just have to do this for Longitude, and it is exactly what I was looking for.   Thanks!